# Subversion Edge console won't start in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, svn

I've installed Subversion Edge (CollabNetSubversionEdge-5.1.5_linux-x86_64.tar.gz) on ubuntu 14.04 LTS using oracle-java8 but both `bin/csvn start` and `service csvn start` lead to the same result:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
$  service csvn start
Starting CSVN Console...
...............
WARNING: CSVN Console may have failed to start.
Could not run the command using user "collabnet".
Advice: Make sure the user "collabnet" has a shell.
If user "collabnet" has a no shell, you can specify one using SU_OPTS if your platform support it.
For example, at the top of this script you can set: SU_OPTS="-s /bin/bash".
Another workaround would be to use a OS service management tool if available on your platform.
OS service management tools supported by this script are described at the top of this script.
```

The user `collabnet` has both a shell and an HOME dir.

Answer (score 1):

**Two reasons for this issue:**

**1)** Files permission issue.

**2)** Run the command without "**sudo**".